# form changes width after deplayment (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Login form changes width size after I deploy my app.

Local build:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJwRr.png)

Deployed build after 'npm run build':[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKx0f.png)

Please assist if you can

Comment: check if the same css classes are applied in local and deployed version. Then you can narrow down the issue. It might be an issue, with your build process, where you havent bundled correctly the css files

Comment: Okay I don't think my deployed version is using the entire is using the entire dom... just the small piece in the middle... but how do I make it use the hole dom because I didn't do anything on my css to course this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding this

```
#root
{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

on my index.css file